# Making a module dependent python code run on machine without the module

Tags: python

I am just done with the pretty piece of code. It uses some of the modules which doesn't come preinstalled in the python. Now the issue is that to make it run a user would have to install all the modules required on the system.
How can I save user from this pain?
Is there any way to factor out only those functions in the modules which are being used and somehow package them with the code I wrote over it?
One thing that I have in my ming right now is to write a assistvie shell script to ease out users effort. But again installing modules might give pain and through errors on various system. I can't handle that. 
Please suggest me something.
Thank you

Edit1:  I was little worried about the complexity to install whole of the library. I am working on the cv2 module for python (which in the background is implemented in C/C++) I can't afford to ask user install whole of the library when at the end of the day I am just using a bunch of functions from it.
PS: It took me couple of hours to install opencv

Comment: write a setup.py to include all the dependencies? so all modules can be installed in one command.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have the module xyz

Normally you would install that using pip

```
pip install xyz
```

For some reason you don't have access to doing that in the environment where it's suppose to run, so instead go and clone/download the xyz repository from github into your application (preferably as a git submodule)

The xyz repo will probably look some thing like this.

```
XYZ repo (dir)
- xyz (dir) <-- this is where the actual module is
- readme.md
- setup.py
```

Now you applications directory looks like this:

```
My app (dir)
- XYZ repo (dir)
- __init__.py
- myapp.py
```

To be able to import xyz in myapp.py you need to add a symlink to the module directory of the XYZ Repo

```
ln -s XYZ\ Repo/xyz xyz
```

You application now looks like this:

```
My app (dir)
- XYZ repo (dir)
- xyz
- __init__.py
- myapp.py
```

And you can now import xyz in your code.

DISCLAIMER: This will only work for pure python libraries, if it has c dependencies they will need to be built during install time, and you need to have access to pip or at least to run the build script yourself.
Also any dependencies of the xyz package must be installed in the same way

Comment: Thank you. But I was little worried about the complexity to install whole of the library. I am working on the cv2 module for python (which in the background is implemented in C/C++) I can't afford to ask user install whole of the library when at the end of the day I am just using a bunch of functions from it.

Comment: You need to use something like `cx_freeze`  this will package your entire script and all the dependencies into one small file. Completely self contained. I have used cx to make .exe's for windows machines. Not sure what else it can be run to package but im sure anything. Try google "porting" python and see what turns up